# Prove a lemma of the conjugate gradient method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, conjugate-gradient

To me is given the following task in connection with the conjugate gradient method with a positive definite and symmetric matrix:

> $$ \begin{array}{l} \text { Let } g^{i} \neq 0, i \leq t \in
> > \mathbb{N} \text { : Show } \\ \operatorname{span}\left\{g^{0}, \ldots,
> > g^{t}\right\}=\operatorname{span}\left\{A^{0} g^{0}, \ldots, A^{t}
> > g^{0}\right\} \\ \operatorname{span}\left\{g^{0}, \ldots,
> > g^{t}\right\}=\operatorname{span}\left\{d^{0}, \ldots, d^{t}\right\}
> > \\ \left(g^{t}, d^{i}\right)=0, \quad i \leq t-1 \\ \left(d^{t}, A
> > d^{i}\right)=0, \quad i \leq t-1 \end{array} $$

I would have thought that I could show this, more or less for all statements at the same time, by means of induction and have now started with the beginning of induction and the induction step:

Induction start $(t=0)$:
For $t=0$ the following relationships apply:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\operatorname{span}\left\{g^{0}\right\}=\operatorname{span}\left\{A^{0} g^{0}\right\}=\operatorname{span}\left\{d^{0}\right\} \\
\left(g^{0}, d^{0}\right)=0 \text { and }\left(d^{0}, A d^{0}\right)=0
\end{array}
$$

Induction step (**edit**):
$$
g^{k+1}=g^{k}+\alpha_{k} A d^{k}
$$

From this follows:
$$
\alpha_{k} A d^{k}=g^{k+1}-g^{k}
$$

Shows that $\alpha_{k} A d^{k}$ lies in $\operatorname{span}\left\{g^{k+1}, g^{k}\right\}$.

$A d^{k}$ is orthogonal to $A d^{0}, \ldots, A d^{k-1}$, since the directions $d^{i}$ are orthogonal in pairs.

$\alpha_{k} A d^{k}$ is in the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span}\left\{A d^{0}, \ldots, A d^{k-1}\right\}$ with respect to span $\left\{g^{k+1}, g^{k}\right\}$.

This means that $\operatorname{span}\left\{g^{k}, A d^{k}\right\}=\operatorname{span}\left\{A d^{0}, \ldots, A d^{k-1}\right\} \oplus \operatorname{span}\left\{g^{k+1}, g^{k}\right\}$ is a direct orthogonal decomposition.

Is that correct so far?

> conjugate gradient method: Start: $x^{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n},
> > d^{0}:=-g^{0}=b-A x^{0}$ Iteration: $$ \begin{aligned} t & =0,1,2,
> > \ldots \\ x^{t+1} & =x^{t}+\alpha_{t} d^{t},
> > \alpha_{t}=-\frac{\left(g^{t}, d^{t}\right)}{\left(d^{t}, A
> > d^{t}\right)} \\ g^{t+1} & =g^{t}+\alpha_{t} A d^{t}(g^{t+1}=A
> > x^{t+1}-b=\underbrace{A x^{t}-b}_{g^{t}}+\alpha_{t} A d^{t}) \\
> > d^{t+1} & =-g^{t+1}+\beta_{t} d^{t}, \beta_{t}=\frac{\left(g^{t+1}, A
> > d^{t}\right)}{\left(d^{t}, A d^{t}\right)} \end{aligned} $$

Comment: using induction is correct, then use the relation of $g^{k+1}$ can be represented by $g^k$ and $Ad^{k}$ to show it is in $span (g^k, Ad^k) = span(Ad^0,\cdots, Ad^{k-1})\oplus span(Ad^k)$.

Comment: hallo @Yimin: I'm still not getting any further with the induction step (is what I wrote in my edit correct)?